# Bootstrap - Align columns vertically

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, multiple-columns

I have the typical row with 2 columns. In the first one I have an image 200 x 200 pixels. In the second one I have a title and a subtitle.

I need to align vertically the title and subtitle of the second column to the bottom of the first column.

```
<div class="row" style="padding: 50px 0;">
  <div class="col-md-4 fotoTop"><img src="" alt="200x200"></div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div><h1 style="padding-left: 0 !important;">Armand Ashante</h1>
         <p><strong>Civil/Structural Engineer - Project and Construction Management</strong></p>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/surracom/uazqp989/2/)

Comment: check flex box, it will work i guess

Comment: I guess so. Manyhanks. I did use another solution. I'll publish it later. You can give a look here: http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height